# Angular HashLocationStrategy removes last element from path after loading app

Tags: angular, hash-location-strategy

I'm trying to get Angular's `HashLocationStrategy` working together with generic base href (to deploy app under any path - pretty much solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664188/how-to-deploy-an-angular-app-so-that-it-works-under-any-path))

My `@NgModule`:

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
      path: 'history',
      component: HistoryComponent
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: IndexComponent
    },
  ]),
  ...
],
providers: [
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
  ....
]
```

Together with `<base href='.'>` I'm able to deploy this app to any path (my app is served from CDN), but when last element of the path does not end with trailing slash, Angular is removing it. For example when entering url `X` it's changed to `Y` by Angular:

```
X -> Y
http://example.com/my/app/ -> http://example.com/my/app/#/
http://example.com/my/app -> http://example.com/my/#/
```

What should I change in my configuration/base href to get second example to work (desired effect: when entering `http://example.com/my/app` I want Angular to change nothing in url or to change it to `http://example.com/my/app#/`

(I'm using Angular 4.3 in this app)

Comment: have you used something like this { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }?

Comment: Have you tried "./" : <base href='./'>

Comment: @QuentinPetel yes - didn't work (still url was changed)

Comment: I found this solution, not using <base href> at all, but providing APP_BASE_HREF inside the AppModule : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501062/5784818